# How can I bind to an array on my input using Vuetify/Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using [Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) on a project and everything is working very well. I am trying to add some custom error messages to my `username` input. For example, if a user trying to sign in is not found - I want to display that message.

I am able to pass a single value using `:error-messages="errors.myMessage`. Works great!

However, I'd like to set multiple values to that error message. For example, if:

- The user is not found
- The user does not have permission
- ???

Here is what I am doing that works:

```
...
type="email"
:error-messages="errors.userNotFoundException"
v-model="form.username"
...
```

According to the Vuetifyjs docs, I can pass a string or an array to `:error-messages`. Looking through the playground, I've tried this:

```
...
type="email"
:error-messages="[errors.userNotFoundException, errors.notAuthorizedException]"
v-model="form.username"
...
```

However, when the page renders, the `username` field is showing as invalid & no errors are showing. Ideally, I'd like to show different messages based on the error that is returned on the same input. An array make sense here...

[image]

To set the values, I am doing this based on my Axios response:

```
data() {
    return {
        errors: {
            notAuthorizedException: '',
            userNotFoundException: '',
        },
},
...
.catch(error => {
    console.log("error: ", error);

    if (error.code === 'NotAuthorizedException') {
        this.errors.userNotFoundException = error.message;
    }
...
```

What is the correct way to show multiple message(s) for the same input? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a single error message is the way to go. You can simply change it based on what the axios error is.

```
type="email"
:error-messages="loginError"
```

js:

```
data() {
    return {
      loginError: ''
    }
},
...
.catch(error => {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    this.loginError = error;
...
```

Comment: Oh my. Serious face palm.. I was _so_ focused on showing different messages. It is so obvious. Thank you for humoring me. :)